# Undefined reference to function in C (using other file's function)

Tags: c, reference, undefined

I am trying for hours to begin an exercise and I am stack in the beginning! Please Help!

my code is sth like:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "heap.h"
#include "BF.h"

int main() {

char *myfile;
myfile = "file1";

HP_Create(myfile);

return 0;
}
```

**BF.c**

```
void Init(){
blabla...
}

int BF_Create(const char* filename){
blabla...
}

void PrintError(const char* message){
blabla...
}
```

**BF.h**

```
#ifndef BF_H_
#define BF_H_

void Init();
int BF_Create(const char* filename);
void PrintError(const char* message);

#endif
```

**heap.c**

```
#include "BF.h"
#include "heap.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int HP_Create(char *fileName) {
  Init();

  if (BF_Create(fileName) < 0) {
            PrintError("Error creating file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            return -1;
        }

  return 0;
}
```

**heap.h**

```
int HP_Create(char *fileName);
```

I execute:

```
gcc -o example main.c BF.c heap.c
```

I get the following errors:

```
heap.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `Init'

heap.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `BF_Create'

heap.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `PrintError'
```

Comment: Compiles and links fine here (GCC 4.9.2).

Comment: What happens if you remove the preprocessor statements from `BF.h`? You can declare a function prototype as many times as you wish, providing they are all the same.

Comment: It works for a different main and BF.c BF.h.

Comment: It works for a different main and BF.c BF.h
the problem starts when i try to use in file heap.c,  a function from BF.c

Since compiles and links in Kenney's  machine, there is sth wrong there with mine!

Thank you all for the fast response!
I 'll try compiling the code in a different machine tomorrow...